# Running make via Dockerfile results in Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable

Tags: docker, format, dockerfile, exec

Upon running a tool I installed via the `RUN` section in my Dockerfile I get following error:

```
root@3a583c845e0f:/code# ./trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval
bash: ./trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I saw that the data type differs when I `make` a tool inside my Dockerfile:

```
root@4fc24a0ff259:/code# file trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval
trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|PIE>
```

and when I `make` the tool inside the created container:

```
root@4fc24a0ff259:/code# file trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval
ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b3f7494afc9a0ec7b634583a2f4401f62d716ec9, with debug_info, not stripped
```

After making the tool inside the container it works fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Create work directory.
WORKDIR /code

# Copy files (unnecessary files excluded via .dockerignore).
COPY . .

# Install requirements.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Download and make trec_eval.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install wget -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential -y && \
    wget https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/releases/download/v9.0.7/trec_eval-9.0.7.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf trec_eval-9.0.7.tar.gz && \
    cd trec_eval-9.0.7 && make && cd ..

# Expose port.
EXPOSE 8050

# Start app.
CMD [ "python", "./run-comparator/app.py" ]
```

How can this behaviour be explained?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently. The issues was with the line `COPY . .` - I had previously built the binaries on my mac so they were copied and then `make` saw the copied binaries and assumed they were already built.